# How to select good knot sequences for "scipy.interpolate.make_lsq_spline"

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I want to create a B Spline smoothing a 2D data sequences using `scipy.interpolate.make_lsq_spline`.

```
x = [0., 0.37427465, 0.68290943, 0.83261929, 1. ]
y = [-1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

But, I don't know how to select proper `t`, the error message does not make sense for me.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.interpolate import make_lsq_spline

In [3]: x = [0., 0.37427465, 0.68290943, 0.83261929, 1. ]

In [4]: y = [-1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]

In [5]: t = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.,1.,1.,1 ]

In [6]: spl = make_lsq_spline(x, y, t)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4440a73d26f0> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 spl = make_lsq_spline(x, y, t)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py in make_lsq_spline(x, y, t, k, w, axis, check_finite)
   1513
   1514     # have observation matrix & rhs, can solve the LSQ problem
-> 1515     cho_decomp = cholesky_banded(ab, overwrite_ab=True, lower=lower,
   1516                                  check_finite=check_finite)
   1517     c = cho_solve_banded((cho_decomp, lower), rhs, overwrite_b=True,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_decomp_cholesky.py in cholesky_banded(ab, overwrite_ab, lower, check_finite)
    280     c, info = pbtrf(ab, lower=lower, overwrite_ab=overwrite_ab)
    281     if info > 0:
--> 282         raise LinAlgError("%d-th leading minor not positive definite" % info)
    283     if info < 0:
    284         raise ValueError('illegal value in %d-th argument of internal pbtrf'

LinAlgError: 5-th leading minor not positive definite
```

Is there any guideline for selecting proper knot sequense `t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem. Due to your example, I think I can tell what is going wrong.
From a linear algebra point of view, you are asking for a solution of a problem which cannot be uniquely solved. You provide 11 knots t which means that there are 11-3-1 = 7 coefficients to be determined since you try to fit with a spline of degree k=3 (default of make_lsq_spline). Evaluating on 5 points x, the left-hand side of your equation system is given by a 5 x 7 matrix D. D is of full rank in the example but this does not help. The 7 x 7 matrix N = D.T@D is only positive semidefinite. Two eigenvalues are 0. It cannot be inverted and your problem therefore cannot be solved uniquely.
One solution would be to get rid of 2 knots, say the knots at 0.25 and 0.75. The four-folded knots at the boundaries you should keep when working with splines of degree 3 because you most likely want your interpolation spline to jump there.
To sum up, knots got to be chosen in such a way that the interpolation problem is uniquely solvable.
I also tried to add some code illustrating what I was trying to say.
Hope that helps.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as sciint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0., 0.37427465, 0.68290943, 0.83261929, 1.]
y = [-1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]
t = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.,1.,1.,1 ]

splines = []

for k in range(7):
    coeff    = np.zeros(7)
    coeff[k] = 1.
    splines.append(sciint.BSpline(t,coeff,3))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,3)
dom    = np.linspace(0.,1.,1000)

for count,axes in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axes.plot(dom,splines[count](dom))
    if count == len(splines)-1:
        break
    
data = []

for spline in splines:
    data.append(np.vstack(spline(x)))
    
D = np.hstack(tuple(data))    
N = D.T @ D

sing = np.linalg.eigvalsh(N)

print(sing)

t2 = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.5,1.,1.,1.,1 ]

bspline = sciint.make_lsq_spline(x,y,t2)

ax[2,1].plot(x,y,'r')
ax[2,2].plot(dom,bspline(dom),'m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to my question, but `scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline`:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline which is introduced from scipy 1.10.0 can be used for my usecase.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.interpolate import make_smoothing_spline

In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: x = [0., 0.37427465, 0.68290943, 0.83261929, 1. ]

In [5]: y = [-1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]

In [6]: spl = make_smoothing_spline(x, y)

In [7]: plt.plot(x, y, "rx")
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x12f101e70>]

In [8]: x_grid = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 400)

In [9]: plt.plot(x_grid, spl(x_grid), label='Smoothing Spline')
Out[9]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x12f102830>]

In [10]: plt.legend(loc="best")
Out[10]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x12473bc40>

In [11]: plt.show()
```

[image]